# How do I avoid stackoverflowexception within a finite loop (C#)

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a code to find prime numbers within a given range. Unfortunately I'm running into some problems with too many repetitions that'll give me a stackoverflowexception after prime nr: 30000. I have tried using a 'foreach' and also not using a list, (doing each number as it comes) but nothing seems to handle the problem in hand.

How can I make this program run forever without causing a stackoverflow?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        List<double> Primes = new List<double>();

        const double Start = 0;
        const double End = 100000;

        double counter = 0;
        int lastInt = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < End; i++)
            Primes.Add(i);


        for (int i =0;i< Primes.Count;i++)
        {
            lastInt = (int)Primes[i] - RoundOff((int)Primes[i]);

            Primes[i] = (int)CheckForPrime(Primes[i], Math.Round(Primes[i] / 2));

            if (Primes[i] != 0)
            {
                Console.Write(", {0}", Primes[i]);
                counter++;
            }
        }


        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nNumber of prime-numbers between {0} and {1} is: {2}, time it took to calc this: {3} (millisecounds).\n\n" +
                          "                                          The End\n", Start, End, counter, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    public static double CheckForPrime(double Prim, double Devider)
    {
        if (Prim / Devider == Math.Round(Prim / Devider))
            return 0;
        else if (Devider > 2)
            return CheckForPrime(Prim, Devider - 1);
        else
            return Prim;
    }
    public static int RoundOff(int i)
    {
        return ((int)Math.Floor(i / 10.0)) * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to not use a recursive algorithm. Refactor your `CheckForPrime()` method to use an iterative approach instead.

Comment: as @itsme86 said, avoid recursion. BTW: use `int` instead of `double`, you can get a huge speedup.

Comment: I second the "don't use recursion" comments, especially since C# doesn't support Optimized Tail Recursion (to my knowledge).  If you still insist on using a recursive algorithm, you can reduce the call stack size and get a speed up by using a Dictionary.  When you compute a prime, use the function's parameters as the key, and the computed result as the value.  In the future when it is called, see if you have that key already, and pull from the dictionary instead of recomputing.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx